# How to reproduce or symbolicate error log from reviewer?

Tags: ios, alamofire, crash-log

Recently I submitted an app to appstore but I keep getting some error logs that I can't reproduce. I tried many times on simulator and device with the same ios version but no result. The error log is like below:

```
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           some.identifier [877]


Date/Time:           2018-02-15 08:54:22.2476 -0800
Launch Time:         2018-02-15 08:54:15.9742 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.5 (15D60)
Baseband Version:    
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100c8c704
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   hc-ios-consumer                 0x0000000100c8c704 0x100c70000 + 116484
1   Alamofire                       0x0000000100f67268 0x100f30000 + 225896
2   Alamofire                       0x0000000100f495c0 0x100f30000 + 103872
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183fbea54 0x183fbd000 + 6740
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183fbea14 0x183fbd000 + 6676
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183fcb698 0x183fbd000 + 59032
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845e7344 0x1844fc000 + 963396
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001845e4f20 0x1844fc000 + 954144
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184504c58 0x1844fc000 + 35928
9   GraphicsServices                0x00000001863b0f84 0x1863a6000 + 44932
10  UIKit                           0x000000018dc5d5c4 0x18dbea000 + 472516
11  some-identifier                 0x0000000100c751d8 0x100c70000 + 20952
12  libdyld.dylib
```

How can I find what causes the crash?

Comment: Que!?  How is the sample log shown above supposed to help you identify the cause of your specific problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)